# Can someone tell me why (return DayName;) causes an ERROR cause it's an unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, error-handling

Here is my code:

```
namespace Hello_World
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetDay(0));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string GetDay(int DayNum)
        {
            string DayName;

            switch (DayNum)
            {
                case 0:
                    DayName = "Sunday";
                    break;
            }

            return DayName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: string DayName = string.Empty;

Comment: Answer to your why? -> Because it is not assigned any value  when it is declared. You need to initialize it either in `switch default` case or when you when you declared this variable

Comment: Think about when value of DayNum is 1 i.e `DayNum = 1`, what value will be stored in `DayName`?

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH @PrasadTelkikar , I didn't know it was obligated to use a "default:

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the value of a variable, you need to assure that, no matter which path the execution takes, your variable will receive a value. As it is, you didn't assure that, because there is a path which the execution may take and your variable won't receive any value. That is when it doesn't go in the switch-case, which is an optional path.

Also, this validation doesn't take semantics in consideration. Example:

```java
int a;
int b = 1;

if (b == 1) {
    a = 2;
}

return a; // This causes an error
```

Although the execution will always enter the if, since `b` will always equal 1, ifs are always considered as an optional code block, so it's not considered assured that `a` will have a value in time for `return`.